# Two different schemas and JAXB Marshaller

Tags: java, jaxb, schema, marshalling

Lets suppose that we have XML consnensual with Schema and Java class with some common fields:

```
    <objectFromSchema1>
     <element1/>
     <commonElement1/>
     <commonElement2/>
     <element2/>
    </objectFromSchema1>

   public class X {
     private String element1;
     private String commonElement1;
     private String commonElement2;
     private String element2;
   }
```

Is a nice way to unmarschall such kind of XML to Java object ? It means: convert all consensual fields and set null on rest.

Comment: may I know the reason why you are asking this?
It is a very convenient and easy way

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "yes". This is the way JAXB works. Take a look on basic JAXB tutorial, e.g. https://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JAXB/article.html

Answer (score 1):

"YES"

If you have an xsd you also could generate automatically these classes by `<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>`maven plugin.

An example of your Class

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "objectFromSchema1", propOrder = {

})
@XmlRootElement(name = "objectFromSchema1")
public class ObjectFromSchema1
implements Serializable
{

    private final static long serialVersionUID = 12343L;
    protected String element1;
    protected String element2;
    protected String commonElement1;
    protected String commonElement2;
    public String getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }
    public void setElement1(String element1) {
        this.element1 = element1;
    }
    public String getElement2() {
        return element2;
    }
    public void setElement2(String element2) {
        this.element2 = element2;
    }
    public String getCommonElement1() {
        return commonElement1;
    }
    public void setCommonElement1(String commonElement1) {
        this.commonElement1 = commonElement1;
    }
    public String getCommonElement2() {
        return commonElement2;
    }
    public void setCommonElement2(String commonElement2) {
        this.commonElement2 = commonElement2;
    }

}
```

Main method to use it

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException {
        final JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFromSchema1.class);
        final Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        final ObjectFromSchema1 objectFromSchema1 = new ObjectFromSchema1();

        objectFromSchema1.setCommonElement1("commonElement1");
        objectFromSchema1.setCommonElement2("commonElement2");
        objectFromSchema1.setElement1("element1");
        objectFromSchema1.setElement2("element2");

        m.marshal(objectFromSchema1, System.out);
    }
```

output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<objectFromSchema1>
    <element1>element1</element1>
    <element2>element2</element2>
    <commonElement1>commonElement1</commonElement1>
    <commonElement2>commonElement2</commonElement2>
</objectFromSchema1>
```